# The Input Tag Helper are not found in cshtml.cs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I try to use the following expemple of Input Tag Helper in my code, but it isn´t working.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/input-tag-helper

I want to use a list of objects to display in a table and read there values from inputs. Display the data works, but not reading the Inputs.

cshtml

```
@page
@{
    var days2 = @Model.days;

}
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <button asp-page-handler="Go" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.days[0].Name)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.days[0].Beginn)</th>
                ........
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i =0; i< days2.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input asp-for="@days2[i].Name" class="form-control" value=Tag.Name /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@days2[i].Beginn" class="form-control" value=Tag.Beginn /></td>
                    .....               
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>


    </table>
</form>
```

cshtml.cs

```
[BindProperty]
public List<day> days { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
  days=getdaysvalue();
}

public void OnPostGo()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Tage.Count; i++)
  {
    days[i].Name = days2[i].Name;  //days2 is in the actuell context not given
    days[i].Beginn = days2[i].Beginn;
  }
```

days2 is in the actuell context not given

Comment: Did you tried without value=Tag.Name  ?

Comment: What is the defination for `Tage` and what is the purpose for `var days2 = @Model.days;`?

Comment: Tage is days. I change the german names of variables and there i´ve forgot it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several properties with same name and an ID in the view, and in the end it just reads the value of one of the properties.

you can try this

```html
           @for (int i =0; i< days2.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="Name_@i" type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" value="@Tag.Name" /></td>
                    <td><input id="Beginn_@i" type="text" name="Beginn" class="form-control" value="@Tag.Beginn" /></td>
                    .....               
                </tr>
            }
```

and in the RazorPage

```cs
public void OnPostGo(List<string> Name,List<string> Beginn)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Tage.Count; i++)
  {
    days[i].Name = Name[i]; 
    days[i].Beginn = Beginn[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: I had initialize days again, but then it work :)
Realy thanks you saved my chance to get my favorite job

Comment: Good luck... ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Razor Page, it helps to bind the model with `[BindProperty] public List<day> days { get; set; }`, you should try to access the submit model by `days` instead of variable in `view`.

Try like:

1. `PageModel`

   ```
   public class TestModel : PageModel
   {
       [BindProperty]
       public List<day> days { get; set; }

       public void OnGet()
       {
           days = new List<day> {
               new day{ Name = "D1", Beginn = "B1"},
               new day{ Name = "D2", Beginn = "B2"},
               new day{ Name = "D3", Beginn = "B3"},
           };
       }

       public void OnPostGo()
       {
           var result = days;
       }
   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   @page
   @model CoreRazor.Pages.Books.TestModel
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
   }

   <h1>Test</h1>

   <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
       <button asp-page-handler="Go" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.days[0].Name)</th>
                   <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.days[0].Beginn)</th>
                   ........
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.days.Count; i++)
               {
                   <tr>
                       <td><input asp-for="@Model.days[i].Name" class="form-control" /></td>
                       <td><input asp-for="@Model.days[i].Beginn" class="form-control" /></td>
                   </tr>
               }
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </form>
   ```