# Bind a Variable to the asp-for tag inside of loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a class of people and hobbies

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
}

public class Hobby
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

On my web page I would like to loop through the properties in Hobby to produce a table.
The idea is, if I change the Class the data being displayed/requested will automatically change.

Currently on the web page I have

```
@if (Model.Hobbies.Count>0)
{

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>Hobby 01</td><td>Hobby 02</td><td>Hobby 03</td><td>Hobby 04</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Frequency</td>
            @for (int i =0; i < Model.Hobbies.Count; i++)
            {
            <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="Hobbies[i].Frequency" asp-for="Hobbies[i].Frequency" value="">  </td>
            }

        </tr>
        @foreach(var property in Model.Hobbies[0].GetType().GetProperties())
        {
        <tr>
            <td><label>@property.Name</label></td>
            @for (int i =0; i < Model.Hobbies.Count; i++)
            {
            <td>sds <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="Hobbies[i].@property.Name" asp-for="Hobbies[i].GetProperty(property.Name)" value="">  </td>
            }
        </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

The 1st asp-for, where I am using the name works fine

```
 asp-for="Hobbies[i].Frequency"
```

But I can not get the 2nd one to work using a variable:

```
 asp-for="Hobbies[i].property.Name"
```

- I have tried a number of ways, and I am sure there is a method I could use I just don't know what it is.

Any help would be great.

Comment: An example of your question has been solved in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57011552/7086678)

Comment: `asp-for` expects a model *expression*, so you cannot pass something that would be required to be executed (especially through reflection).

Answer (score 0):

As poke said in comment , `asp-for` expects a model expression

`asp-for` attribute in `input` tag helper generates the `id` and `name` HTML attributes for the expression name specified in the asp-for attribute. `asp-for="Property1.Property2"` is equivalent to `m => m.Property1.Property2`. The name of the expression is what is used for the asp-for attribute value.

You could customize a tag helper which sets id , name and value of input from the `asp-for-model` attribute and `asp-for-prop` attribute in the view . This workaround may not be smart, but it can solve your problem.

Here is the working code :

- ConditionTagHelper

  ```
  [HtmlTargetElement("input",Attributes = "asp-for-prop")]

  public class ConditionTagHelper:TagHelper
  { 
     [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for-prop")]
     public ModelExpression Property { get; set; }

     [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for-model")]
     public ModelExpression Hobby { get; set; }


    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
  {
      var propName = Property.ModelExplorer.Model.ToString();
      var modelName = Hobby.Name.ToString();
      var modelExProp = Hobby.ModelExplorer.Properties.Single(x=>x.Metadata.PropertyName.Equals(propName));
      var propValue = modelExProp.Model;

      var para = modelName + "." + propName;


      output.Attributes.Add("id", para);
      output.Attributes.Add("name", para);
      output.Attributes.Add("value", propValue);

      base.Process(context, output);

  }
  ```

  }
- In the _viewImports, add the tag helper namespace which matches the
  namespace used in the class.

  ```
  @addTagHelper *, MVCTest
  ```
- The view

  ```
  @foreach (var property in Model.Hobbies[0].GetType().GetProperties())
      {
          <tr>
              <td><label>@property.Name</label></td>
              @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Hobbies.Count; i++)
              {
                  <td>sds <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for-model="@Model.Hobbies[i]"  asp-for-prop="@property.Name"/>  </td>
              }
         </tr>
      }
  ```